# Cannot expand text view smoothly in iOS 11 Swift

Tags: swift, textview

I'm try to expand the text view when I click the Read More Button.It works on device below iOS 11 but It cannot expand very smooth in iOS 11 version. why?

When I tapped the read more button will run this code.

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
let txtView = cell2.aboutTxtView!
let txtStr = cell2.aboutTxtView.text!
let btn = cell2.aboutReadBtn!

if self.aboutTag == 0{
    let height = getRowHeightFromTextView(strText: txtStr, txtView: txtView)
    cell2.aboutTxtView_HeightConstraint.constant = height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    btn.setTitle("Show Less", for: .normal)
    self.aboutTag = 1
    self.aboutHeight = 140.0 + height - 84.0
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
else
{
    cell2.aboutTxtView_HeightConstraint.constant = 84
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    btn.setTitle("Read More", for: .normal)
    self.aboutTag = 0
    self.aboutHeight = 140.0
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        return aboutHeight
    }
}
```

Below iOS 11 Version

[image]

iOS 11 Version

[image]

What i have tried.

(1)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

(2)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if #available(iOS 11, *)
    {
        self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding this three code.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350318/8393564
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46257601/8393564

Answer (score 0):

Don't update table view just update single cell inside table view and set height for cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        return aboutHeight
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Then Update only **About Me** cell. It will only update single cell so cell expansion will be smooth.

```
// Add your code to update cell height 
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

**Update :**

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)

let txtView = cell2.aboutTxtView!
let txtStr = cell2.aboutTxtView.text!
let btn = cell2.aboutReadBtn!

if self.aboutTag == 0{
    let height = getRowHeightFromTextView(strText: txtStr, txtView: txtView)
    cell2.aboutTxtView_HeightConstraint.constant = height
    btn.setTitle("Show Less", for: .normal)
    self.aboutTag = 1
    self.aboutHeight = 140.0 + height - 84.0
}
else
{
    cell2.aboutTxtView_HeightConstraint.constant = 84
    btn.setTitle("Read More", for: .normal)
    self.aboutTag = 0
    self.aboutHeight = 140.0
}
tableView.endUpdates()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        return aboutHeight
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Try removing `estimatedHeightForRowAt`.

Comment: Check out Update and  use same code and remove  `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`  and What i have tried 1 and 2.

Comment: I have removed the code in "what i have". and the constraint height of the textview will not update if I remove `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` ,  and also the 'laggy' or 'scroll to top' effect still at there when i tapped the button

Comment: `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` Not require for expanding cell in Uitableview . If you change in height and content of cell then it will updated.

Answer (score 0):

If @Sid's answer doesn't solve your problem.

You should call layoutIfNeeded, `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` after any updates in the UI. Also, use the main queue for it.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

It will update the views frames.

Comment: I also tried `self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` and `cell2.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: yup, cell2.aboutTxtView_HeightConstraint.constant, this is the height constraint