# UITableView deleteRows animation bug (it always fade regardless rowAnimation variable)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, catransaction

I'm deleting a row from `UITableView` with `RowAnimation` `.left` which should be very simple 
by writing the following
 `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)`, but here comes the problem the `UITableView` doesn't respect the `rowAnimation` I'm passing `(left, right,top,bottom,fade)`, it only show the normal animation

I have tried different solutions like

```
beginUpdates()
deleteRows(at: indexPath, with: .left)
endUpdates()
```

---

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.myViewModel?.items?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.top)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
})
self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
CATransaction.commit()
```

---

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
// ...
self.tableView.endUpdates()
self.tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

I have also tried to use `performBatchUpdates`, im pretty sure its kind of bug since it was working in previous versions of iOS, im using iOS 13 & swift 5

There are a few other answers like [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303649/ios-11-uitableview-delete-rows-animation-bug), but none of them are working

Comment: Not sure if related, but you can remove `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` - I think these are no longer needed.

Comment: did you try to use `performBatchUpdates`?

Comment: what does "doesn't respect the `rowAnimation` I'm passing" mean?

Comment: @koen yes I have already it, not working also

Comment: @hongsy I mean when I use
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
the row should animate to the left , but actually it animate as a fade, if you tried it in a sample project whatever rowAnimation u are passing the actual animation is fade

Comment: please [edit] your question to add in details mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @javierrivarola I have just tried it now, not working, whatever rowAnimation variable you pass it always fade

Comment: Have you tried using `UITableViewRowAnimation.none`?