# How do I re-achieve a clear color UITableViewCell mask effect during cell dismissal on iOS 11 that previously worked on iOS 10?

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios10, calayer, ios11

**The Preface**

I have a working custom `UITableViewCell` dismissal animation on iOS 10. The way it is implemented is as follows:

1. User presses the submit button
2. A custom view is created, positioned and inserted at index zero of the `UITableViewCell`'s subviews (underneath the cell's `contentView`)
3. The `contentView` is animated out of frame while the custom view's alpha is animated to 1.0
4. When the `contentView` is fully out-of-frame, the native `UITableView` method `deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)` is called. The `UITableViewCell` collapses and the custom view is masked behind the previous `UITableViewCell` as it collapses.
5. The cell (and hence all of it's subviews including my custom view) is deleted.

Below is a slow-animation of it working:

[image: UITableViewCell mask working on iOS 10]

*Note*: The `tableView` has a clear background color, allowing a custom view (the blue) to show behind it. Each cell has a `containerView` which contains all the content of the cell. The `containerView` and `contentView` both have clear background colors. All is fine and dandy.

**The Problem**

Migrating my app to iOS 11, this animation no longer works properly. Below is a slow-animation of it no longer working anymore.

[image: UITableViewCell mask working on iOS 11]

As you can see, the custom view is overlayed *on top* of the previous cell upon cell dismissal with no changes to my code.

**Investigation thus far**

So far I've determined that the anatomy of a `UITableView` has changed from this:

```
UITableView
    UITableViewWrapperView
        cell
            custom view
            contentView
            cell separator view
        cell
        cell
        cell
    UIView
    UIImageView  (scroll view indicator bottom)
    UIImageView  (scroll view indicator right)
```

To this: (`UITableViewWrapperView` has been removed)

```
UITableView
    cell
        custom view
        contentView
        cell separator view
    cell
    cell
    cell
    UIView
    UIImageView (scroll view indicator bottom)
    UIImageView (scroll view indicator right)
```

One thing I noticed about this `UITableWrapperView` is that its layer's `isOpaque` property is true and `masksToBounds` property is false while the `UITableView` and all of the `UITableViewCell`s are opposite. Since this view was removed in iOS 11 this might contribute to why I'm having the erroneous effect. I really don't know.

*Edit*: Another thing I found was that the `UITableWrapperView` in the working example inserts a mystery `UIView` at the zero index of it's subviews (all the `UITableViewCell`s) which properties `isOpaque` is set to true and it has a `compositingFilter`. This view is subsequently removed after the animation is complete. Since `UITableWrapperView` is removed in iOS 11, this view is, by association, also missing.

**Question**

First of all, does anybody know why this this change in behavior is occurring? If not, is there an alternative way to achieve the effect that was working in iOS 10 in a better way? I want clear `UITableViewCell`s but have a custom view that displays behind each cell upon dismissal that is masked by the other clear `UITableViewCell`s when dismissed as shown in the first gif example above.

Comment: Seems like you used a undocumented feature, which has been removed now https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82320

Comment: @TarunLalwani I know that already. I wasn't specifically using that view by design, it just worked and now I'm finding out it's *because* of that view. I'm looking to achieve the same effect now that it's gone.

Comment: Got it, possible to get a minimal debug repo? That would give this question a better chance of getting solved

Comment: Unfortunately not in it's current form. I can try and recreate the effect in another sample project if this post doesn't receive any ideas in the near future.

Comment: if possible then can you give code link ? so i can check it

Comment: @NiravKotecha see above comment...

Comment: Did you solved?

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S I believe it's solved

Comment: @Callam, lol Yep bro

Comment: @Aaron I reproduced your issue and sending the cell to the back actually resolves the clipping issue in the row animation.

Answer (score 1):

Before you delete the row, send the cell you're deleting to the back of the table view's subviews.

```
tableView.sendSubview(toBack: cell)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
```

If you don't have the cell, you can retrieve it using the index path.

```
guard let cell = tableView.cell(for: indexPath) else { return }

// ...
```

This should work with an adjustment to the view hierarchy.

[image: View hierarchy adjustment]

***CardTableViewController.swift***

```
class CardTableViewController: UITableViewController, CardTableViewCellDelegate {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    // MARK: Properties

    private var cards: [Card] = [
        Card(text: "Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum."),
        Card(text: "Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam."),
        Card(text: "Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.")
    ]

    var selectedIndex: Int { return segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex }
    var tableCards: [Card] {
        return cards.filter { selectedIndex == 0 ? !$0.isDone : $0.isDone }
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return tableCards.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CardTableViewCell

        cell.card = tableCards[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    // MARK: CardTableViewCellDelegate

    func cardTableViewCell(_ cell: CardTableViewCell, didTouchUpInsideCheckmarkButton button: UIButton) {

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

        cell.card?.isDone = button.isSelected
        cell.card?.dayCount += button.isSelected ? 1 : -1
        cell.customView?.dayCount = cell.card?.dayCount

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0.3, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            cell.checkmarkButton?.superview?.transform = .init(translationX: cell.frame.width, y: 0)
            cell.customView?.alpha = 1
        }) { _ in
            self.tableView.sendSubview(toBack: cell)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
        }
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func didChangeSegmentedControl(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

***CardTableViewCell.swift***

```
@objc protocol CardTableViewCellDelegate {
    func cardTableViewCell(_ cell: CardTableViewCell, didTouchUpInsideCheckmarkButton button: UIButton)
}

@IBDesignable class CardTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet var checkmarkButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet var customView: CardCustomView?
    @IBOutlet var delegate: CardTableViewCellDelegate?
    @IBOutlet var taskTextLabel: UILabel?

    // MARK: Properties

    var card: Card? {
        didSet {
            updateOutlets()
        }
    }

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        checkmarkButton?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {

        super.prepareForReuse()

        card = nil
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    private func updateOutlets() {

        checkmarkButton?.isSelected = card?.isDone == true ? true : false
        checkmarkButton?.superview?.transform = .identity

        customView?.alpha = 0
        customView?.dayCount = card?.dayCount

        taskTextLabel?.text = card?.text
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func didTouchUpInsideCheckButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

        delegate?.cardTableViewCell(self, didTouchUpInsideCheckmarkButton: sender)
    }
}

class CardCustomView: UIView {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet var countLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var daysLabel: UILabel?

    // MARK: Properties

    var dayCount: Int? {
        didSet { 
            updateOutlets()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        updateOutlets()
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    private func updateOutlets() {

        let count = dayCount.flatMap { $0 } ?? 0

        countLabel?.text = "\(dayCount.flatMap { $0 } ?? 0)"
        daysLabel?.text = "Day\(count == 1 ? "" : "s") in a row"
    }
}
```

***Card.swift***

```
class Card: NSObject {

    // MARK: Properties

    var dayCount: Int = 0
    var isDone: Bool = false
    var text: String

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. `UITableView` already stacks cells with the top cell on top of the stack so the cell being animated away is already underneath. Regardless, this didn't solve the issue but thanks for trying!

Comment: @Aaron the cells are ordered in the view hierarchy as they are ordered in the table so the last cell is the uppermost view. I recreated your UI and the issue in your GIF, and `sendSubview(toBack:` fixed it. The only thing I failed to mention was that I had put the custom view in the cell's content view and the original contents of the content view inside its own above the custom view. I'm guessing that's what's making it work for me so I have updated my answer to include a screenshot of the view structure.

Comment: This is a similar proposed solution to @Marek R but to no avail. I wish it solved it!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think a missing `UITableViewWrapperView` is a problem.
This is parent view and parents can't obscure child views.

Note that problem is which cell obscures which. In first case row A obscures row B and in second row B obscures row A (in this case your custom B cell has transparent background).

So looks like Apple has screw up relations between cells. To fix it I would try to fix this relations. So before second part of animation starts I would try:

[bring cell to back](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622618-sendsubview)

```
cell.superview.sendSubview(toBack: cell)
```

This shouldn't break anything (on older iOS versions) and should resolve issue wiht iOS 11.

Comment: First off, the cell's superview is the UITableView in iOS 11 so I could just call directly from that. That said, it does send the cell to the back but it doesn't produce any different result. The custom view is still not masked "behind" any other views in the table view unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I spent many days studying but failing.

**iOS10**

After `deleteRows`, `TableViewCell` has a view with a `compositingFilter` property, the value is `copy`, which that the view hide all view behind this.

We can try to remove subview of `TableViewCell` generated while `deleteRows`. Then iOS 10 will behave like iOS11.

Then we can try add a view(`UIView()`) to `TableViewCell` again and set `compositingFilter` to `copy` (String), it will re achieve `in iOS10` again.

But any action failure in iOS11. It will produce a black background in iOS11.

I believe the behavior of layer was changed on iOS11.

Maybe we have to think about give up temporarily use `up` animation in `ios11` when the background of `TableViewCell` is transparent.

Comment: Yes I posted about this `compositingFilter` in my original question. I assume that it had something to do with how the cell animation is behaving differently.

Answer (score 1):

I faced such an issue after reviewing the app on iOS 11, the issue was the animation when deleting rows from the table view:

[image]

It is clear that collapsing animation is improper because there is more than one row to be deleted.

Here is the responsible code for expanding/collapsing the rows:

```
// inserting rows:                
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 4 + count, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 5 + count, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 6 + count, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()

// deleting rows:
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 4 + count, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 5 + count, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 6 + count, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

<sub>obviously, there is also code to edit the data source array.</sub>

The reason of causing this issue was -*simply*- the assigned [UITableViewRowAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewrowanimation) to [automatic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewrowanimation/1614906-automatic); All I did was changing the animation to be `fade`:

```
// inserting rows:                
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 4 + count, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 5 + count, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 6 + count, section: 0)], with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()

// deleting rows:
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 4 + count, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 5 + count, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 6 + count, section: 0)], with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

And the output has been fixed to be:

[image]

**Also**

You might want to check the following question that could be related to your issue:

- [iOS 11 UITableView delete rows animation bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303649/ios-11-uitableview-delete-rows-animation-bug)
- [iOS 11 UITableView bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223541/ios-11-uitableview-bug)

Comment: If you look at it in slow motion it is indeed still overlapping upon dismissal.

Answer (score 0):

#### I found the solution for the `UITableView` with fixed sized cells

[image: presentation of the solution in action]

In this approach, I decided to add a supplementary view to the content view of the `UITableViewCell` and animate it's height constraint to `0` alongside the row delete animation.

**To keep things simple I will present only the key points of this solution.**

- User taps remove button.
- Cell moves the inner content view to the right.
- Table view calls `deleteRows(at:with:)` method.
- Cell animates the height of the supplementary view to `0`.

I won't be describing entire auto layout setup here because it will obscure the main idea of the solution. All the building blocks are fairly simple but there are a few of them. You can find a full working project in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kamil-szostakowski/stack-overflow/tree/SO-46984873).

---

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work very well with dynamic height cells due to the animation timing. I'm not sure that it will solve your problem because as far as I can see you are using the dynamic height cells. 
However, I hope it will push you in the right direction or help someone having a similar problem.

Comment: You're right, unfortunately it doesn't work so well with the dynamic height cells that I have.